# Referring to a dynamically generated resource within a for loop

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am trying to generate two `google_monitoring_alert_policy` with corresponding two `google_monitoring_notification_channel` via a `for` loop:

```
variable "projects" {
  type        = map
  default     = {
    "project_A" = {
      "email" : "a@example.com"
    }
    "project_B" = {
      "email" : "b@example.com"
    }
  }
}

resource "google_monitoring_notification_channel" "basic" {
  for_each      = var.projects
  project       = each.key
  type          = "email"
  labels = {
    email_address = each.key.email
  }
}

resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy" {
  for_each     = var.projects
  project      = each.key
  notification_channels = [
    google_monitoring_notification_channel.basic[each.key].id
  ]
}
```

This does not seem to give an error, but after deploying the `notification_channels` seem to be empty inside the alert policy. I want to check if `google_monitoring_notification_channel.basic[each.key].id` is the correct syntax to refer to resources generated via a `for_each` loop?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's the correct way to use references when using a for_each.

After reading the GCP doc, the `notification_channels` is waiting for an ID like : `projects/[PROJECT_ID]/notificationChannels/[CHANNEL_ID]`.

`google_monitoring_notification_channel.basic[each.key]`.id is like `[CHANNEL_ID]`

Try the following :

```
   resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy" {
     for_each     = var.projects
     project      = each.key
     notification_channels = [
       "projects/${each.key}/notificationChannels/google_monitoring_notification_channel.basic[each.key].id"
     ]
   }
```

Comment: Managed to resolve. The correct syntax should be `google_monitoring_notification_channel.basic[each.key].name` instead